# "Observer ... was not registered" error

Tags: android

I'm working on an Android application, and when I attempt to display large amounts of data in  a `listview`, I receive the following error:

```
01-24 18:06:32.214: 
INFO/System.out(9244): 
  EX:Observer android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver@43c9b200 
  was not registered.
```

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm having the same problem. I'm not sure why outis is telling you to accept any answers here when there are no answers :s

Answer (score 14):

i got this error too.
in my case this exception (Observer * was not registered.) was thrown because i called

```
setAdapter(Adapter)
```

multiple times.

for example:

```
MyAdapter (extends BaseAdapter) vla;
ListView lv;

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  vla.clear();
  vla.add(tv);
  lv.setAdapter(vla);
}
```

The fix here is to place 

`v.setAdapter(vla);`
 
outside the loop, thereby avoiding multiple calls.
 
after fix no more exception throws.
best regards, flood. (fldr atincircle mail dot ru)

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem and it turned out to be a threading issue. Multiple threads were calling `setAdapter` which does not seem to be threadsafe. After making sure that all `setAdapter` calls are done on the same thread, the problem was solved.

What worked nicely for me, was to force my code to change it only on the UI thread:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rc_view);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(items));
            }
        });
```

Comment: I also fixed it with running on ui thread. Simply moved my code inside the run(){}

Answer (score 2):

I've ran into this problem multiple times when dealing with listviews. If you're using a custom adapter with an edit text involved, you'll want to do a clearFocus() before you refresh the adapter. Observer not registered is caused by the listview deleting a child that has focus on the activity

How I do it:
this is the view holder for my custom adapter

```
class viewHolder {
    public viewHolder() {
        views = new ArrayList<viewInfo>();
    }

    public int position;
    public ArrayList<viewInfo> views;
    public View view;
}
```

After which i invoke an unfocusAll() which consists of:

```
public void unFocusAll() {
    viewHolder holder = (viewHolder) v.getTag();
        if (holder != null) {
            holder.view.clearFocus();
        }
}
```

So before you invoke your listview you have to do

```
CustomAdapter aa = new CustomAdapter();
if (aa != null) {
  aa.unFocusAll();
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid your code examples are not very clear. In your unFocusAll() function, what is v? Additionally, is unFocusAll a method of CustomAdapter? Why do you even need the viewHolder class?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today too and flood's answer helped me solving it. In my case the error would show up whenever I switched back to my application from another one, so the method setAdapter was allways called twice.

This helped me avoid it:

```
if ( pager.getAdapter() == null ){
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

at fragment which  contains the Viewpager

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        viewDestroyed = true;
    }
```

then before you set the adapter check

```
if(viewDestroyed)
  pager.setAdapter(adapter)
```

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Simply *override* in your adapter **onGroupCollapsed**.

Add to your adapter:

```
@Override
public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {

}
```